# Generic query to select from multiple tables in Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, api, rest

In spring boot to do the CRUD ,one has to make repository interfaces & repository implementation classes for each entity. I want to write a single REST API with single dynamic query to select the data from multiple tables. I will pass table_name , column_name , column_value in the payload. Using that payload  will create query like below but dont know the way how to acheive this in spring boot. Query will be created dynamically based on the payload.

```
function ( table_name, column_name, column_value);
Select * from table_name where column_name = column_value ;
```

I don't want to write different functions or repository implementations for different entities. I am new to spring boot. Request to suggest me an approach to proceed on this. Just want to have a dynamic query which will result the data from different tables.

Answer (score 0):

I am sadly not allowed to comment yet, but I would like to help you, anyway..

I would hardly recommend you, to stick to the SpringBoot Crud/JPARepository interface way.
Since it has a lot of perks, DB Query optimization, security concenrs, switching the database, converting to entities out of the box, ...

But if you really want to do it your way, the old school way, you could use jdbc templates:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/

Still IMO huge drawbacks and a really bad trade. Yes you would save some interfaces, but you will need some kind of a Database class, which will manage all that stuff, which spring offers out of the box.. That class will have to map your data from resultsets into classes, then the class will increase in size. which will lead eventually to code smells/ design smells...